# Get rows whose JSON array contains an object with a value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that returns one JSON column named `record`, which is generated by a subquery.

`SELECT record FROM (my json query) records;`

Each record contains an array of tag objects:

```
{
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": 'foo'
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": 'bar'
    }
  ],
  // other props
}
```

I want to modify my query to select all `records` where `tags` contains a tag with a specific ID but I'm not sure how to go about that without adding another subquery. Are there any functions or operations I'm missing that can make this possible using just the where clause?

In pseudo-code, is there anything like this I can do?

```
SELECT record FROM (my json query) records
WHERE 3 = ANY(get_ids_from_objects(record->'tags', 'id'));
```

For code reasons, I'd also prefer not to have to modify the subquery that creates the JSON structure, which is why I've excluded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the contains operator `@>`

```
select *
from (your query)
where record @> '{"tags": [{"id": 3}]}'
```

This assumes that the column `record` is of type `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not, you need to cast it: `record::jsonb`

Comment: @chrispytoes: fixed it, sorry